# How to add more fields in flow without errors?

Tags: community, visual-workflow, automation, visual-flows, flow-builder

I used this link(https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/build-a-simple-flow/create-or-update-a-contact) to create or update contacts. I finished everything and it does create contacts. Right now I am trying to add fields like email, phone, and so on. How can I add more fields without getting errors? I added fields but received errors like "The flow failed to access the value for contact. Email because it hasn't been set or assigned.". I will appreciate any help thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps for adding an extra field, like 'email' to the Contact Info screen from that Trailhead project are as follows:

- Drag the 'email' component across to the screen
- Give it a sensible API Name and label
- Expand the 'Advanced' section and check 'Manually assign variables'
- In the Value field of the Advanced section add {!contact.Email}

That is all you need to do to add another field to that Flow.

Comment: Thank you! It worked!

Comment: Yes, because you have already set up the Contact Record Variable, all you are doing is adding another input for it in the screen and assigning the value to the Contact Record field.  Just repeat for any other Contact field you want to put on the screen.  The key part is the manual assignment of variables - select the right Contact field to assign the value to.